# Views Entity reference (user): how to show profile values of respective user only

Tags: 7, views, entities

[image]i have a rather complex view and have troubles with showing the correct values. im trying to focus on the main issue.

there is a node (team) with entity reference fields to multiple users. the node has for instance two referenced user (UID 80 with 56 points on his profile, UID 23 with 23 points). now, my problem is that i cant get the view to show the correct values (points) of the respective user only. i have installed the views distinct module, but i still cant get the correct values.

what i would need is something like this:

user / points

80 / 56

23 /23

what it does is now is that it shows the values of all users that are referenced (without the views distinct module). with the views distinct module enabled it shows sometimes the values of the first user, sometimes the values of the second - but it does not show the correct values.

i hope this makes some sense. if not, i can post the whole view, but its rather complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

came up with a solution that works for me. 
first, ive added to the view the username field for the referenced users. this outputs the (two) different usernames of the people who are referenced.

second, ive added a global field as **a filter** called "Global: Fields comparison" that compares the name of the team_member with the name of the referenced user. now this shows only one correct entry.

hope this helps someone.